# One-to-one relationship in Entity Framework states that Multiplicity is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In our MVC4 application we have a `WeekDay` Model:

```
public class WeekDay
{
    [Key]
    public int WeekDayId { get; set; } 
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dag")]
    public string Day { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Shop")]
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
}
```

And `Shop` model:

```
public class Shop
{
    public int ShopId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Winkel")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int WeekDayId { get; set; }
    public virtual WeekDay WeekDay { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

We need a one-to-one relationship from `WeekDay` to `Shop` and the other way around (so that every shop has a weekday and vice versa). Unfortunately the code above gives the following error:

```
Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Shop_WeekDay_Target' in relationship 'Shop_WeekDay'. Because 
the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of 
the Dependent Role must be '*'.
```

We've tried various things found on the internet to solve this issue but none seem to work (it did build when we added two primary keys, but then it fails while running the seed method and we get this error: `The index 'IX_ShopId' is dependent on column 'ShopId'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ShopId failed because one or more objects access this column.`).

Does anyone know how a one-to-one relationship can be made in this case?

/Edit Adding:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<WeekDay>()
         .HasRequired(a => a.Shop)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(u => u.ShopId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>()
                    .HasRequired(a => a.WeekDay)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(u => u.WeekDayId);
```

To the `DbContext` makes a succesful migration, but on `update-database` gives the error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.WeekDays_dbo.Shops_ShopId'
>   on table 'WeekDays' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous
>   errors.

And setting `WillCascadeOnDelete` to false gives the error:

> The index 'IX_ShopId' is dependent on column 'ShopId'. ALTER TABLE
>   ALTER COLUMN ShopId failed because one or more objects access this
>   column.

/Edit 3

My database structure looks as follows:

[image: Like this]

Now I "solved" the issue by not making the one-to-one relationship only one way, so that to match the `Shop` with the `WeekDay` I need to query the `WeekDay` table first and then see which shop matches. Then I can use the `ShopId` in further queries to only select the `Categories` from the current shop. It would have been cleaner if you could go from `Shop` to `WeekDay` so that I only need to query once.

I do not care if it is one to many if it is hard to make (I will only use one from the many), but it should be the other way around (from shop to weekday instead of weekday to shop). The one to many is the wrong way around as can be seen in the upper right.

Comment: Can you post your table definitions as well?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll What do you mean with table definitions? Isn't it so that te models define the tables?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll - this is code-first database design. The tables are generated from the code.

Comment: Depends on which approach you take to create the model, however based on your follow-up question it sounds like you are using code first, is that correct?

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon There is actually nothing in the code that 100% guarantees it is code first. It could be code second.

Comment: I would STRONGLY suggest you create a test database, and design the table / relationship you are looking for, then generate an EF model from that database and compare it to all of your code here.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll - I disagree. The custom display names on the tables along with the direct inclusion of model building code that is defining the relationships points out to me that this is definitely code-first database design. Plus, OP specifically mentioned updating the database after modifying the code.

Comment: Recreating my whole database structure in a designer is too much work. I'm sure it must be possible by using code first.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I notice is here:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<WeekDay>()
         .HasRequired(a => a.Shop)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(u => u.ShopId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.WeekDay)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.WeekDayId);
```

Each of the configurations above defines a one-to-many relationship. If you want a one-to-one relationship it should look something like this (check my syntax as I am not at my dev workstation to verify):

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<WeekDay>()
         .HasRequired(a => a.Shop)
         .WithRequiredDependent();
```

Or, optionally, you can do this as well:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<WeekDay>()
         .HasRequired(a => a.Shop);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.WeekDay);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but also when changing the definitions (or removing them) the error when adding a new migration remains: `Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Shop_WeekDay_Target' in relationship 'Shop_WeekDay'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.`

Comment: Do you have a third entity called Target? It would seem that is where the issue lies.

Comment: No. These names are automatically generated. My database structure looks as follows: http://i.imgur.com/TuqcgZL.png

Now I "solved" the issue by not making the one-to-one relationship only one way, so that to match the `Shop` with the `WeekDay` I need to query the `WeekDay` table first and then see which shop matches. Then I can use the `ShopId` in further queries to only select the `Categories` from the current shop. It would have been cleaner if you could go from `Shop` to `WeekDay` so that I only need to query once.